# How to get a grsecurity kernel on Debian Wheezy using the linux-patch-grsecurity2 package?

Tags: linux, debian, security, compiling, grsecurity

There is a package [linux-patch-grsecurity2](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-patch-grsecurity2). But it seems to be lacking documentation.

How to make use of linux-patch-grsecurity2 to get a grsecurity enabled kernel?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a custom installer created for Debian by someone else which will do everything for you automatically?

https://github.com/rickard2/grsecurity-Debian-Installer

Else isn't it just a case of doing things the old way? Namely, patching things from source? You seem to be asking for instructions on how to patch your kernel for which there are instructions all over the web?

https://www.howtoforge.com/hardening-the-linux-kernel-with-grsecurity-debian

Answer (score 0):

The grsecurity-Debian-Installer script that dtbnguyen found could be worth a try.

That said, however, i think this is still a very valid question, because the idea of a package coming from Debian itself should be that if simplifies your life somehow/somewhat, thus avoiding at least part of the hasle of patching a vanilla kernel yourself.

In this case, however, it is not clear if the package is little more than just a way of becoming the grsecurity patch itself, plus some useful dependencies.

Look at the README files in /usr/share/doc/linux-patch-grsecurity2
and the note in the package description:

> Furthermore, this patch will NOT apply to Debian kernels. You will
>   have to use vanilla kernel sources to apply this patch. Reasons are
>   documented in README contained within the package.

So, all in all you will end up doing repeating more or less the steps of the script above, except for using the patch from the Debian package instead of downloading one from grsecurity.

You'll find a few hints in `/usr/share/doc/README-kernelpatch.Debian`